# opencart .htaccess redirect subfolder to subdomain language not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, opencart, subdirectory

I installed opencart in a subfolder `web8.us/shop/` and redirected permanently to `shop.web8.us`.

My .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{http_host} ^web8.us [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.web8.us/$1 [L,R=301]

#this is the magic line below here
RedirectMatch 301 ^/shop/(.*)$ http://shop.web8.us/$1
```

All works good without languages, but when you try to change the language from English to Spanish it is still stuck on English. Any ideas?

Comment: show us the link of  spanish version of your website as example,an that should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you change your store URL in the admin and your config files from the `/shop/` URL to the subdomain version? If not, then that is likely the issue. If you have, it sounds like a redirect is happening when any page is submitted, causing the `POST` data to be lost (the data that is sent to tell OpenCart that you want to change language)

Comment: Hi,thank you for your answer,but the fold is main,i not explain good what exactly is the situation,in the root directory i have wordpress webpage (web8.us),in subfolder /shop/ have opencart,before with out .htaccess lini how i put :

Comment: @Web8.us - Please follow my advice above. Your OpenCart config is set to `http://www.yoursite.com/shop/` where it should be `http://shop.yoursite.com/`. You need to change this or it's not going to work with a lot more than the language switcher

Comment: Thank you very mach Jay Gilford,all works good and no need RedirectMatch 301 ^/shop/(.*)$ http://shop.web8.us/$1 in .htaccess,one more time thank you

Comment: @Web8.us - No problem. Please mark this question as answered using the tick on the left next to my answer